# regex restrict to one semicolon

Tags: java, regex

I'm making a code which takes a file and checks if it's a valid Java code, must be done using regexes.

I run over every line and checks if it end with ; or { or }.
however, I can't seem to manage to limit it to only 1 occurence of it.
i.e
both

```
int i=0;
```

and

```
int i=0 ;;;;;;;
```

would pass..
The regex I'm using right now is

```
.+;{1}\\s*$
```

tried many other options, non seems to work.
any help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Read about greedy regex matching (or greedy quantifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `.` will also match a semicolon, so your expression will match all but the last semicolon as part of the `.+`.

To avoid this, you could match any character *except* a semicolon by using `[^;]`. i.e.

```
[^;]+;\\s*$
```

However, you should be aware that `int i=0 ;;;;;;;;;` is perfectly valid Java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure, that there is only one semicolon in the whole row, then use:

```
^[^;]+;{1}\\s*$
```

This is not a proper check for a valid java source however.

Comment: what do you mean not a proper check?

Comment: Java files can contain rows that not ending in { } or ;
They can conain rows wih more semicolon after each other, and so on. It is much more complicated, than you could just write it down with a few character long regexp.

Comment: Oh, this. yeah, I know. but in the exercise we are not required to check these kind of things. we need to write a Simplified-Java compiler which uses regexes to verify a code. S-Java has none of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the regexp: `.+` will match any character, including all but the last of your `;`'s.

You need to exclude `;` from the first part of your regexp so that you can match "Anything but a ; followed by exactly one ;" (and once you get that working, you can expand your character class to capture also { and } if you wish)

HTH